# error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘GtkPlotBorderStyle’

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I change the extension from `testgtkplot.c` to `testgtkplot.cc` which is one of the GtkExtra examples, and no any other code change. it does not compile and gives many error messages.

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘GtkPlotBorderStyle’
```

What is the reason for that? How can I overcome this problem? I'm trying to code a kind of CPP wrapper.

Comment: C++ have stricter type checking. For example, enumerations can no longer be implicitly converted to `int`, which is probably the cause of your error in the question.

Comment: that's completely as what you said. i changed all numbers to corresponding enum string. Then compiled and worked. Thank you very much.